# jQuery AJAX not entering "success"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "src/cookiecheck.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            success: function(json){
                if(json.visitedBefore!="true"){
                    $("#cookiepolicy").fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
        window.alert(5);
        $.ajax({
            url: "src/lessons.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            success: function(json){
                window.alert(1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So this is my jQuery part of the application it executes the first ajax call successfully and display 5 from the "window.alert(5);" The second call is made but for some reason success is not triggered. Here is how the output from "lessons.php" looks like

```
{"ID":"5"}
{"Name":["111","2","3","4","5","123123"]}
{"Location":["1112","2","3","4","5","3123123"]}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: probably need to see your lessons.php as well

Comment: Check your devtools network tab... Is the post being made? What is the http response?

Comment: The problem is within "lessons.php". As others have mentioned, you will need to open up Developer's tools and check the network tab to see what is being returned when you hit this file. My guess is this file either does not exist or is throwing an error.

Comment: There is no error in lessons.php, as Joe said the output is not a valid JSON and after a little research I found that the problem is because there are more than one root elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid json:

```
{"ID":"5"}
{"Name":["111","2","3","4","5","123123"]}
{"Location":["1112","2","3","4","5","3123123"]}
```

Perhaps format it like this:

```
{
"things": {"ID":"5"},
"names": {"Name":["111","2","3","4","5","123123"]},
"locations": {"Location":["1112","2","3","4","5","3123123"]}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the commas

Comment: Well I am newbie in using json and PHP so may I ask you to help me with formatting the output? Currently I am using array_push($arrName['Name'], $row['lessonName']);
array_push($arrLocation['Location'], $row['fileLocation']);
So I can add elements to the arrays and then displaying them with json_encode

Comment: Sounds like your output currently is `echo json_encode($arrName); echo json_encode($arrLocation);`. You want to change it to: `echo json_encode(array('names'=>$arrName, 'locations'=>$arrLocation));`

Comment: Used 
$string = array("ID" => $ID, "name" => $arrName, "location" => $arrLocation);
 echo json_encode($string);
And it worked

Comment: I named it like that because when I started writing the code it was used to hold some short strings containing information was there an error (and the type of it) or was it successful. And yeah I changed it